# mismatched input 'if' expecting 'end of line without line continuation'

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I'm having this "mismatched input 'if' expecting 'end of line without line continuation'" error in pinescript with the following block of code:

```
arrow(direction, bar, color) =>
    if direction == "up"
        plotchar(bar, high, "\u2191", color, size = size.normal)
    else if direction == "down"
        plotchar(bar, low, "\u2193", color, size = size.normal)
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `plot*()` functions in a local loop.

You can apply your condition to the `series` argument of your `plot()` call as a workaround so it would conditionally plot.